# Android - Open PDF document and know current page

Tags: android, pdf, webview

How can I open a PDF document that is on my device and know at every moment the page where I am?

That is, I open my PDF within a Webview. How can I know which page I find myself on when I click inside it?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with MUPDF android that will open source and allows you all thing that you want.